# How do I use storyboard aspect ratio to set buttons with equal with automatically?

Tags: ios, storyboard, nslayoutconstraint

Basically how do I use the aspect ratio constrain properly to set all buttons equally spaced with same width and height. I got the heights but then the four buttons using the aspect ratio constraint is confusing me a little bit. I can't seem to figure out the multiplier. There is no code for this, it is all using storyboards.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you want the buttons to have equal width & height (ie a square) or do you want all buttons to have the same width as one another and the same height as one another ?

Comment: same width as one another

Comment: The use an equal width constraint between one button and the others and set an aspect ratio constraint between one button's width and the width of superview. The multiplier is just the ratio of the two widths, say 1:5 and you will need to set some spacing between the buttons. The easiest way to do this is to use some UIViews as spacers - again set equal widths and an aspect ratio width constraint

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to have buttons with equal widths.

1. Select all the buttons and apply the following constraints. Make sure that the buttons do not overlap or else the leading and trailing constraints will be set with the wrong button.
   [image]
2. Once that is done, select all the buttons and update their frames

That should do the trick.

Also, make sure the view that is holding the buttons has its constraints set.